# Get Scaled QML Item's TopLeft Corner Postion in Flickable

Tags: qt, qml

How can I get the top left corner position of a scaled Image inside a Flickable item. The position should be in relation to the top left corner of the Flickable.

Image does not have x.topLeft that returns a value

Comment: what is `QItem`?

Comment: In my case it's an Image

Comment: @JokerMartini provide a [MRE]

Comment: each Item has x,y,width,height that usually relative to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [mapFromItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapFromItem-method) method which is derived from Item ( Flickable inherits Item). In that method, first argument will be your image and the x,y would be zero(0) to represent topLeft corner of the image. As per the documentation, you don't need to do further calculations as transformations would be taken into account.

From the Qt5 documentation :

> The following properties of the item are used in the mapping: x, y,
>   scale, rotation, transformOrigin, and transform.

So you will get something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Flickable {
    width: 200
    height: 200
    contentWidth: image.width
    contentHeight: image.height

Image { 
    id: image; 
    source: "bigImage.png"
    scale:0.5 
}

function getImageTopLeft(){
     return mapFromItem(image,0,0); //returns topleft coordinates of the image relative to topleft of the flickable
    }
}
```